# Backup de todas as tabelas com exceção de uma

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

Em MySQL podemos realizar backups via terminal da seguinte forma:

#### Base de dados

```
mysqldump nomeBaseDados > meuFicheiroBackup.sql
```

#### Tabela

```
mysqldump nomeBaseDados nomeTabela > meuFicheiroBackupDaTabelaX.sql
```

Como posso fazer um backup de todas as tabelas da minha base de dados `nomeBaseDados` com excepção de uma chamada `tabelaCorrupta` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O `mysqldump`tem uma flag exatamente para isso:

```
--ignore-table
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
mysqldump -u username -p database --ignore-table=meubanco.tabelaCorrupta > database.sql
```

Lembrando que, se necessário, você pode usar o `--ignore-table` mais de uma vez:

```
mysqldump -u username -p database --ignore-table=db.tab1 --ignore-table=db.tab2 ...
```

Veja mais detalhes no **[manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table)**.

Comment: No MariaDB fiz da seguinte forma:  mysqldump -u root -p <dbname> --ignore-table=<dbname>.{tabela1,tabela2,tabela3} > backup.sql

Comment: @dark777 isso é uma característica do shell usado (expansão de parâmetros), e não um recurso do MariaDB. Se você der um `echo a.{1,2,3}` no mesmo shell o resultado também será `a.1 a.2 a.3`, pois a expansão ocorre antes da execução. Na prática você gerou uma linha com `--ignore-table=` várias vezes, conforme mencionado na resposta.

Comment: sim fiz isso pra nao ter que ficar escrevendo --ignore-table varias vezes.